# db error to update Cedtag component from 2.5 to j3.4X

Tags: components, joomla2.5, tag-cloud

I made ​​change to the Cedtag component v2.6.2 (This version works only in Joomla 2.5)
I modified the following functions

```
JToolBarHelper::editListX('');
JHtmlBehavior mootools
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
JView.
JModel
.JController
. JFile
```

After this change,component does installed in joomla 3.4x without problems. Tags are displayed however when i click on any tag  i get the following error:

```
1054
Unknown column 'a.parentid' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT   a.id,a.title,a.created,a.alias,a.modified,a.images,a.created_by as contactid,u.name as author,a.created_by_alias as created_by_alias,COUNT(a.id) as total,a.introtext,a.fulltext,a.access,a.state,a.publish_up,a.hits,a.parentid as parent_id,a.catid as catid,cc.title as category_title,cc.title as section,cc.alias as parent_alias,CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug,CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cc.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cc.id, cc.alias) ELSE cc.id END as catslug,CHAR_LENGTH( a.`fulltext` ) AS readmore FROM z4hqk_content AS a INNER JOIN z4hqk_categories AS cc ON cc.id = a.catid INNER JOIN z4hqk_users AS u ON u.id=a.created_by WHERE a.id in (1) AND (a.access IN(1,1,5) AND (a.state = 1 or a.state = 2) AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2015-09-05 12:13:05') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2015-09-05 12:13:05') AND (a.state != -2)) AND cc.published = '1' GROUP BY (a.id) ORDER BY a.ordering LIMIT 0, 10`
```

I know it can be hard to tell but does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: and what comes at 'enter code here'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem solved with create a row named "parentid" in joomla 3x com_content db